# How to check if I can 'make' a specific number from a set of numbers?

Tags: list, numbers, set, find, combinations

Let's say we have a list:

`list = [10,10,20,20,20,50,100,200,200]`

and a specific number we want to make using numbers from the list:

`x = 110`

What is the easiest and the **fastest** way to check if we can 'make' the number we want?

**Adding is the only operation allowed !!!**
So possible solution to our example could be [10+100] or [20+20+20+50] etc. I don't really need to know all the possible combinations, if we find at least one - return true, if none - return false.

Comment: What operations are allowed?

Comment: Multiply by zero and add x.

Comment: I mean, you could do that, if you really allow all operations :)

Comment: Sorry my bad haha. Adding only.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the fastest process, but I do have a solution.

```
flag = False
def f(L, x):
    global flag
    if L == [ ]:
        return
    if sum(L) == x:
        flag = True
        return
    for i in range(len(L)):
        if not flag:
            B = L[:i] + L[i+1:]
            f(B, x)
L = eval(input('Enter the elements: '))
x = int(input('Enter the required sum: '))
f(L, x)
print(flag)
```

Comment: I get `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' when using large set of number (1000+).

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
def f(L, x, p):
    # x is the target sum. Only consider smaller numbers
    L1 = list(filter(lambda val: val <= x, L))

    # There's nothing left to try. This path has no answer.
    if (len(L1) == 0):
        return []

    # The next value to try is the largest, at the right-hand side of the list
    tryNext = L1[len(L1)-1]

    # Jackpot?
    if (tryNext == x):
        retVal = p[:]
        retVal.append(x)
        return retVal
    
    # See if we can get to victory using the largest item on the list

    # Get the sublist to pass to f (all but the last item)
    newL = L1[:len(L1)-1]
    newP = p[:]
    newP.append(tryNext)
    newX = x - tryNext
    result = f(newL, newX, newP)
    return result

def myResult(L, x):
    # Make sure the list is sorted
    L.sort()
    result = f(L, x, [])
    if (len(result) > 0):
        print("Got a result: ",result)
    else:
        print("No answer found")
    return len(result) > 0


L0 = [5,5,10,10,20,20,20,50,100,200,200]
x = 110


print(myResult(L0, x))
```

Comment: It may not always be the smallest answer, but it gives an answer like pulling change from a cash register. Start with the biggest currency you can use that is smaller than the change you need to return; then work your way downwards.

Comment: Testing this works quickly on a list of 1k. You can try like so:

from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint

[...]

seed()
values = randint(0, 50000, 1000)
print(myResult(values, x))

Comment: It doesn't work properly, take L0 = [20,20,20,50] and x = 60 for example. Returns False but what about 20+20+20?

Answer (score 0):

You are right! Here, with numpy to try it out.

```
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randint

def f(L0, x0, L, x, p):
    # x is the target sum. Only consider smaller numbers
    L1 = list(filter(lambda val: val <= x, L))

    # There's nothing left to try. This path has no answer.
    if (len(L1) == 0):
        
        if (len(p) == 0):
            return []

        # Find the next largest number to start with from the original list
        L2 = list(filter(lambda val: val < p[0], L0))
        
        if (len(L2) == 0):
            return []

        return f(L2, x0, L2, x0, [])
        

    # The next value to try is the largest, at the right-hand side of the list
    tryNext = L1[len(L1)-1]

    # Jackpot?
    if (tryNext == x):
        retVal = p[:]
        retVal.append(x)
        return retVal
    
    # See if we can get to victory using the largest item on the list

    # Get the sublist to pass to f (all but the last item)
    newL = L1[:len(L1)-1]
    newP = p[:]
    newP.append(tryNext)
    newX = x - tryNext
    result = f(L0, x0, newL, newX, newP)
    return result


def myResult(L, x):
    # Make sure the list is sorted
    L.sort()
    result = f(L, x, L, x, [])
    if (len(result) > 0):
        print("Got a result: ",result)
    else:
        print("No answer found")
    return len(result) > 0


seed()
values = randint(0, 50000, 10000)
x = randint(1,100000)

print(myResult(values, x))
```

Comment: I got 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison' when using L with 369 elements and x = 10000. To be more precise L consisted of 199 * 10's, 100 * 20's, 40 * 50's, 20 * 100's and 10 * 200's.

Comment: I used sys.setrecursionlimit(5000) and it works now but is there a way to optimize it properly in other way?

Comment: The code could be a little cleaner but I don't know how you could make it much faster. What do you need to optimize for? (e.g., speed; memory consumption; CPU consumption; or some characteristic of the answer, such as smallest number of array elements?)

Comment: Speed and memory, but its okay, code is good enough for me. Thanks a lot!